# How can i add a black layer over top of image with opacity

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, opacity

I would like to know if there is a way i can add a black layer over my image but have it slightly transparent so you can still see the image.

I am using Bootstrap 4 & below is the code i am using including CSS :)

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">    
    <div class="card-overlay" style="background-image: url('img/dirt1.jpg')">
      <div class="white-text text-center">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h3>Project title</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat 
 fugiat, laboriosam, voluptatem, optio vero odio nam sit officia accusamus 
 minus error nisi architecto nulla ipsum dignissimos. Odit
            sed qui, dolorum!.
          </p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="...">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to put the `.car-overlay` div inside a div with the background. This is because if an element has a background image and a background color the background color will appear behind the background image.

```css
.card-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/640/360');background-size:cover;">
      <div class="card-overlay">
        <div class="white-text text-center">
          <div class="card-block">
              <h3>Project title</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat fugiat, laboriosam, voluptatem, optio vero odio nam sit officia accusamus minus error nisi architecto nulla ipsum dignissimos. Odit
                  sed qui, dolorum!.</p>
               <a class="btn btn-primary" href="...">Read More</a>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you didn't want to change your HTML structure you could use CSS3 multiple background with a gradient rather than a background color, because you can't layer background colors.

```css
.card-overlay {
  background:
  linear-gradient(
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  ),
  url('https://placekitten.com/640/360');
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card-overlay">
        <div class="white-text text-center">
          <div class="card-block">
              <h3>Project title</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat
       fugiat, laboriosam, voluptatem, optio vero odio nam sit officia accusamus
       minus error nisi architecto nulla ipsum dignissimos. Odit
                  sed qui, dolorum!.</p>
               <a class="btn btn-primary" href="...">Read More</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You sir are a silent guardian, a watchful protector. A Dark Knight

Comment: @user7804189 I added another solution you might be interested in, using CSS3 multiple backgrounds.

Comment: Is there anyway i can get the image to fill the box so you can see it all. At the minute it only shows a small bit of it. I have tried class="img-fluid" but this makes no difference. Thank you

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, but you can try `background-size:cover;` on the element with the background image. `.img-fluid` only works on `img` elements.

Comment: So the image is only showing a small part of the upper left. I have took a screenshot to show you :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7tit3zk2g0xef1/Screenshot%202017-06-20%2015.46.00.png?dl=0

Comment: Working like an absolute dream now mate thank you :) much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

CSS

```
.container { background-color: #000000;}
.container img { opacity: 0.2; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<img src="#">
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle Example Here...](https://jsfiddle.net/6jsbvhvx/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `after/before` for this

```
.card-overlay{
  position: relative;
}
.card-overlay:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.card-overlay {position:relative;}
.card-overlay:before{    background: rgba(37, 35, 35, 0.07);    position: absolute;    height: 100%;    left: 0;    top: 0;    margin: 0;    width: 100%;    content: ' ';    display: block;}
```